# How can I load a built-and-running java project into an AngularJs application?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

First a bit of context.

I'm working on a online information system built using javascript, angularjs, java and Oracle SQL. My system is based on a very little database, but it requires data and services from 5 other systems my client has, some of them running and some of them currently in development. As you may think, the system currnetly being developed change quite often, causing the services and data I need from them to also change, forcing me to update my system every time.

This kind of system is a requirement made by my client, so there's not much I can do regarding the architecture of the solution.

So, the solution I came up with a solution that I think solves the problem I'm having, and it consists on making an independent mini system of each a separate project (with its own frontend and backend) that I can develop, build and deploy separately, and transform the whole system in a sort of UI that is only able to manage the data present on it's own database.

So. I've been looking around the internet for a way to load a built-and-deployed java project into a HTML-Javascript-AngularJS UI, but I haven't found anything.

Does anyone knows of this is even possible.

Thanks!